# Getting error while uploading file Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

```
form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
<input id="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

At server side

```
include 'reqFunctions.php';
$uploaddir = '/path/';
$idx = "file";
$res = array("success" => true, "status" =>array());
if (isset($_FILES[$idx]) && is_array($_FILES[$idx])) {
    foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            $status = array("success" => true);
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[$idx]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES[$idx]["name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES[$idx]["name"][$key];
            $extension=end(explode(".", $name));
            $newfilename=generateRandomString(10)."_".$timestamp1."_".generateRandomString(10).$extension;
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploaddir.$newfilename)) {
               $status["message"] = "ok";
               $status["path"]="images.smsiland.com/post/large/".$newfilename;
             } else {
                $res["success"] = false;
                $status["success"] = false;
                $status["error"] = error_get_last();
                $status["message"] = "internal server error";
            }
        } else {
            $res["success"] = false;
            $status["success"] = false;
            $status["error"] = $error;
            $status["message"] = "upload error";
        }
        $res["status"][] = $status;
    }
}

echo(json_encode($res));
```

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/upload.php** on line **12**
   {"success":true,"status":[]}

Comment: is `$_FILES[$idx]["error"]` an array? I don't think so.

Comment: please ssee full code http://pastebin.com/zKjgZbP8

Comment: `$_FILES[$idx]["error"]` is a number, not an array. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `foreach` statement only works on arrays, your code has not caused the `$FILES` array to contain arrays because you have not told the HTML that you want it to be an array.

The browser is currently returning a `$FILES` array like this:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxx.bmp
            [type] => image/bmp
            [tmp_name] => \tmp\php73AB.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 78918
        )

)
```

because you have used this HTML statement

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
```

Note all the fields in the files array are scalar fields which is causing the `foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {` to generate a WARNING and then **NOT EXECUTE** anything inside the foreach statement.

```
 foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    $status = array("success" => true);
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            . .
    }
 }
```

I am asssuming this code is just step 1 and eventually you want to allow the script to upload more than one file. If that is that case then the simple solution is to change the HTML for the `<input type="file"...` tag like this

```
<input id="file" name="file[]" type="file" />
```

the browser will then generate the `$_FILES` array like this

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => xxx.bmp
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/bmp
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => \tmp\phpCABF.tmp
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 78918
                )
        )
)
```

And your code will compile as each fields in the `$FILES` array is not itself also an array.

Alternatively you could just add another

```
<input id="file1" name="file[]" type="file" />
<input id="file2" name="file[]" type="file" />
```

Which would have the same effect.

Comment: As I said at the beginning of the answer. Because you have used `<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />` when the browser builds the data that will populate the `$_FILES` array the data inside that array is created as scalar variables and not a set of sub arrays. Therefore `foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] ....` is not an array, therefore PHP errors because a `foreach` can only be used on an array

Comment: php code doesnt have any problem only have to update at input

Comment: Sorry I didnt understabd that last comment

Comment: Yes, maybe it is, but it is not getting executed because it is inside a `foreach` loop that is trying to loop over an array that does not exist. See the answer I changed it a bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

before foreach line code
because there is no array exist in $_FILES[$idx]; it returns 0

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = '/upload/';
    $idx = "file";
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);exit;
    $res = array("success" => true, "status" =>array());
    if (isset($_FILES[$idx]['name']) && is_array($_FILES[$idx])) {
        if(is_array($_FILES[$idx]["error"])){
            foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {
                $status = array("success" => true);
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                //move upload codde goes here
              }
           }
        }else{
            //echo "your code ";
        }

          }

          ?>
```